# How do you round of this

Tags: java, string, exception, double

I'm working on a number converter project on high school, and this is for "length."
My two problems are:

1. How do I round off the result to the 0.00 value?
2. How do I make the exception to allow decimal inputs it shows the error message if the number is not an integer.

Here is my code:

```
double a,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7;  
double c1 = (double) (0.00062);  
double c2 = (double) (39.3701);  
double c3 = (double) (0.001);  
double c4 = (double) (3.28084);  
double c5 = (double) (1.09361);
String b = "Invalid user input";  
try {

a = Integer.parseInt(tl.getText());    
a1 = (a*1000);  
a2 = (a*100);  
a3 = (a*c1);  
a4 = (a*c2);  
a5 = (a*c3);  
a6 = (a*c4);  
a7 = (a*c5);  

tl1.setText(String.valueOf(a1));  
tl2.setText(String.valueOf(a2));  
tl3.setText(String.valueOf(a3));  
tl4.setText(String.valueOf(a4));  
tl5.setText(String.valueOf(a5));  
tl6.setText(String.valueOf(a6));  
tl7.setText(String.valueOf(a7));


}
catch (Exception z) // <<<< THIS T_T  
{  
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, b);  
}
```

Comment: I am using JavaApplication1 - NetBeans IDE 7.4

Comment: You should parse the string using Double.parseDouble, and not Integer.parseInt

Comment: @user3402192 what exception are you getting?

Comment: Ohhhh wow im retarded... sorry i meant how to round it off to this value >>> 0.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign an int parsed value into an double variable, that´s what is causing the error.
You should change the `Integer.parseInt` to `Double.parseDouble`.

Answer (score 0):

To round an int to the nearest hundred just do:

```
Math.round(someNumber/100)*100
```

Comment: i tried using that code but it just ended up with 0.0 as a direct answer no matter what input i give i seem not to be using it correctly though >>>   a4 = Math.round(a4/100)*100;